# Can shields block end crystal explosions in 1.16.5 Java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if a shield could block/reduce the explosion of an end crystal, seeing as it can block creeper explosions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, shields do reduce the damage taken by end crystal explosions.
Shields reduce or nullify damage taken by all explosion types.

Comment: Notably crystal explosions are considerably more powerful than creepers, so the shield won't block as much damage.

Comment: Damn, for some reason I forgot to accept this answer when it was posted! Forgive me for the month-long delay.

Comment: If they do reduce damage in 1.16.5 I haven't noticed. They do block end crystals on 1.19.3 and above, but as a player who plays a lot of crystal pvp, if shields block any crystal damage on 1.16.5, it is negligible enough not to be noticed. They do 10+ hearts of damage after a good hitcrystal even with a shield up.